# Why does a part of the navigation bar disappear when the screen gets smaller

Tags: html, css

I created a nav bar in React and CSS with the following code:

```
<header className="home-header">
      <div className="auth-buttons">
         <input type="button" className="auth-button sign-up-button" value="Sign Up" />
         <input type="button" className="auth-button login-button" value="Login" />
     </div>
     <div className="menus-container">
         My Site
         <span></span>
         <span></span>
         <span></span>
    </div>
</header>
```

and

```
.home-header {
    position: sticky;
    padding: 1.5rem;
    margin-top: 0;
    min-width: 100vh;
  
    background-color: #1441aa;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 30px;
    box-shadow: 0 3px 10px rgb(0 0 0 / 0.2);
  
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-between;
  }

  .home-header .auth-buttons {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    gap: 3px;
    /* margin-left: 10%; */
  }

  .home-header .auth-buttons .auth-button {
    padding: 0.5rem 1.5rem;
    border: none;
  }

  .home-header .auth-buttons .auth-button:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
  }

  .home-header .auth-buttons .sign-up-button {
     border-bottom-left-radius: 1rem;
  }

  .home-header .menus-container {
    /* margin-left: 60%; */
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    font-weight: 400;
  }

  .home-header .auth-buttons .login-button {
    border-top-right-radius: 1rem;
  }
```

But when I make the screen smaller, the right part of the navbar disappears, as shown below:

Full Screen:

[image]

Smaller Screen:

[image]

I want the nav bar to be responsive and get smaller as the screen gets smaller, not disappear. Could you help me?

Comment: This does not appear to be reproducible, with just the code you have given us: https://jsfiddle.net/a5vfdhrm/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because u set `min-width: 100vh;` which referts to the window height. You need to change that to `vw` (viewport width) or use `%`.

```css
.home-header {
    position: sticky;
    padding: 1.5rem;
    margin-top: 0;
    min-width: 100%; // the difference is this value
  
    background-color: #1441aa;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 30px;
    box-shadow: 0 3px 10px rgb(0 0 0 / 0.2);
  
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-between;
  }

  .home-header .auth-buttons {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    gap: 3px;
    /* margin-left: 10%; */
  }

  .home-header .auth-buttons .auth-button {
    padding: 0.5rem 1.5rem;
    border: none;
  }

  .home-header .auth-buttons .auth-button:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
  }

  .home-header .auth-buttons .sign-up-button {
     border-bottom-left-radius: 1rem;
  }

  .home-header .menus-container {
    /* margin-left: 60%; */
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    font-weight: 400;
  }

  .home-header .auth-buttons .login-button {
    border-top-right-radius: 1rem;
  }
```

```html
<header class="home-header">
      <div class="auth-buttons">
         <input type="button" class="auth-button sign-up-button" value="Sign Up" />
         <input type="button" class="auth-button login-button" value="Login" />
     </div>
     <div class="menus-container">
         My Site
         <span></span>
         <span></span>
         <span></span>
    </div>
</header>
```

Answer (score 1):

In the CSS for `.home-header`, `min-width` is sized with the `vh` unit rather than `vw`, meaning it will scale according to the height of the screen rather than the width.

Change `min-width: 100vh;` to `min-width: 100vw;`.

Additionally, your header may get cut off the right side of screen due to its padding. Add the rule `box-sizing: border-box;` so that it will be sized correctly.